# How to Forward Ports to Make My Website Public with Bitnami WAMPstack Apache Server

Tags: apache-http-server

I am working on hosting my first website and need support with making it public. As of now, I have my domain name configured and can access my website on my computer through the domain name. However, I cannot access it on other devices.

Online I heard the only solution to this issue is to forward the ports via WLAN settings for your Wi-Fi router. Unfortunately, this did not work even after double-checking and refreshing the ports (changing both the ports on the server and router forward ports settings to double-check). I contacted both my domain name provider and internet service. They refused to provide me a solution.

Does anyone have any methods for making a website public on your own Apache Server?

Thanks

P.S.: I have dug very deep into the code logs, so if you need to know any more specific information on the issue, let me know. Also, I searched through these forums, forums on other websites, YouTube, and websearches. However, there was no solution that helped me with this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can be the problem here.

1. A Portforwarding needs to be setup on the router. In order to test this, make sure you use your phone, disconnect from wifi and use 4G connection and access the site using the WAN IP address of your internet connection. You often cannot use the WAN IP address of your ISP from within the network due to NAT Hairpinning. Only some enterprise-grade routers often support that, and only after enabling it.
2. By default XAMPP configuration is set to development, and it only works for localhost, not your LAN IP Address. So if your computer is on 192.168.1.4, 127.0.0.1 would work, but 192.168.1.4 would not. Change the configuration until it also works for 192.168.1.4. Only then will it also work from outside your LAN.
3. Make sure your firewall also allows external traffic on the specific port or whitelist your XAMPP program entirely.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to ensure that outbound connections will be allowed in my computer antivirus Domain Profile settings? (Sorry for a late reply, I am taking numerous classes and have had to temporarily switch my focus away from this website.)

Comment: You only open that program or port, not everything.

Comment: How do I find the XAMPP configuration settings?